# How to append entries in fusion table?

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-api-client

I currently update entries to my fusion table with the following AJAX call:

```
                $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=UPDATE <my TABLE ID> SET columnName = 'newValue' WHERE ROWID = '2'&key=<API KEY GOES HERE>",
                       beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <AUTHENTICATION TOKEN GOES HERE>");
                        },
                      success: function(data) {
                      alert(data); 
                      }
            })
```

and it works great!

but I do not want to replace the contents of the entry, I want to append data.  Is there a way to do this without calling the data from the cell I want to modify (i.e., do it in one statement)

Answer (score 0):

To insert data in a fusiontable, you should use an `INSERT` statement, see the [SQL Reference Documentation of the Fusion Tables API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#insertRow).

> INSERT
>
> To insert one or more rows in a table, use the following syntax in an
>   HTTP POST request:
>
> INSERT INTO  ( {, }*) VALUES
>   ( {, }*)
>  { {;INSERT INTO  ( {,
>   }*) VALUES ( {, }*)}* ;}